how can i reference a varchar in postgresql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS boards (
    id           SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    title        VARCHAR(45),
    description  VARCHAR(140)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS posts (
    id           SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    board_id     INTEGER REFERENCES boards(id) NOT NULL,
    board_title  VARCHAR(45) REFERENCES boards(title) NOT NULL
};

I want to use the same technique i used to reference board_id, but it doesnt work.
I tried to TEXT REFERENCES boards(title) NOT NULL too but it doesnt work again.

This doesn't make any sense for two reasons.

You already know exactly what boards row each posts row relates to, you have a foreign-key defined already.
There is no need to store the board title on the posts table - it is defined on boards.

If you really want to do this (and you don't - it's a bad idea) then you need to read the error message that PostgreSQL prints (and which you didn't provide - always provide the error message when asking a question).
there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "boards"

You cannot define a reference to a non-unique column, and title is not unique on the boards table (and can also be null). You would need to make it unique and not null.

I apologise that i didn't provide the error, but your assumption of my error message is correct.
You already know exactly what boards row each posts row relates to, you have a foreign-key defined already.
i need to know to what board the post belongs and for that i need the board title for my function. I tried to find other ways to implement it but i didn't succeed.

It sounds like you may need to read some basic tutorials concerning databases and understand how joins work in queries.
